# fql query wth restfb 1.13

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I am working on upgrading to graph api, I upgraded restfb jar from 1.6 (v1.x) to 1.13(v2.3) my application does 2 things
1) post the document to facebook
2) get the comments on that post.
I am having issues with part 2. For fetching comments my app has a cron job that runs every min to find out what are the new post id for given app id and based on that postid it fetches comments, it used fql for this purpose since it was supported in 1.6, but as I am reading I am finding out that fql is deprecated for v2.1 and higher.
but I found in restfb example that you can create token for older version 2.0 and still call fql something like this

```
 facebookClient20 = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken, Version.VERSION_2_0);

void query() {

List<FqlUser> users =
        facebookClient20.executeFqlQuery("SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid=4 or uid=11", FqlUser.class);

out.println("User: " + users); 

}
```

I am trying to do something like this.. I tried above solution but it did not worked,

```
String wallPost = String.format("SELECT post_id, message, actor_id, created_time, updated_time FROM stream WHERE source_id = %1$s AND actor_id <> %1$s AND created_time > %2$s ORDER BY created_time", userId, lastUpdatedTime);
            queries.put("wallPosts", wallPost); 
FqlMulti fqlMulti = facebookClient.executeFqlMultiquery(queries,FqlMulti.class);
```

this gives me

> com.restfb.exception.FacebookOAuthException: Received Facebook error
>   response of type OAuthException: (#12) fql is deprecated for versions
>   v2.1 and higher (code 12, subcode null)   at
>   com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient$DefaultGraphFacebookExceptionMapper.exceptionForTypeAndMessage(DefaultFacebookClient.java:1239)
>     at
>   com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.throwFacebookResponseStatusExceptionIfNecessary(DefaultFacebookClient.java:1154)
>     at
>   com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequestAndProcessResponse(DefaultFacebookClient.java:1087)
>     at
>   com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequest(DefaultFacebookClient.java:998)
>     at
>   com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.executeFqlMultiquery(DefaultFacebookClient.java:615)
>     at
>   com.piersystem.connectors.facebook.FacebookConnector.processIncoming(FacebookConnector.java:142)

so my question is:

1) is there any alternative for this, restfb documentation doesn't states this in the limitation,
2) what is the alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your Facebook App. It seems the version is not 2.0 as you like to use. This happens if you have a new facebook app, because older graph versions are not supported. RestFB can only define the preferred version, but Facebook may override it.

Why don't you use Version 1.14.0 of RestFB?

Comment: I am using latest restfb.jar but since my app was suing fql I wanted to upgrade to newer version of restfb with minimum changes... I know that in v2.x fql is deprecated, but I was trying to make use of sample code given in restfb.jar example so that I can still use of fql and have less changes in fetching comments.